# ffmpeg not working if run from py2app

Tags: python, tkinter, ffmpeg, py2app

I'm trying to build a simple app that concats 2 mp4 files. It works fine if I run it from the command line, but if I run it from py2app app it doesn't work. If I run the app from within the py2app in the console (eg 'dist/addTag.app/Contents/MacOS/addTag'), it works fine. It only doesn't work if i run the app by double clicking on it. Any ideas? code below

```
#! /usr/bin/python
import argparse
import ffmpeg
import os
import shutil
import sys
from Tkinter import *
import time

fields = 'Input Video', 'Tag Video', 'Output Name'

def fetch(entries, bu, lb, rt):
    bu['state'] = 'disabled'
    lb['text'] = 'working'
    rt.update()
    ffmpeg.concat(ffmpeg.input(entries[0][1].get()), ffmpeg.input(entries[1][1].get())).output(os.path.expanduser("~/desktop/")+entries[2][1].get()).run()
    bu['state'] = 'normal'
    lb['text'] = 'Ready'
    rt.update()


def makeform(root, fields):
   entries = []
   for field in fields:
      row = Frame(root)
      lab = Label(row, width=15, text=field, anchor='w')
      ent = Entry(row)
      row.pack(side=TOP, fill=X, padx=5, pady=5)
      lab.pack(side=LEFT)
      ent.pack(side=RIGHT, expand=YES, fill=X)
      entries.append((field, ent))
   return entries

if __name__ == '__main__':
   root = Tk()
   root.title("Video Maker")
   ents = makeform(root, fields)
   root.bind('<Return>', (lambda event, e=ents: fetch(e))) 
   label = Label(root, text="Ready")
   label.pack(side=LEFT)  
   b1 = Button(root, text='Make Video',
          command=(lambda e=ents: fetch(e, b1, label, root)))
   b1.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)
   b2 = Button(root, text='Quit', command=root.quit)
   b2.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)

   root.mainloop()
```

Comment: do you get an error message?

Comment: nothing. it seems that the app gets to the ffmpeg.concat(....).run() line and stops.

Comment: I not using osx, but with windows I already had problems that double-clicking python files started the wrong version/venv of python, while it worked fine on the console. Could this be the issue here?

Comment: hmm, on OSX it opens the app, I get the window, it just seems to not run FFMPEG, I tried bundling it with the app, but that doesn't work either.

Comment: running python setup.py py2app --emulate-shell-environment
fixed it